# Query multiple GeonameIds in SPARQL query on wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata, geonames, wikidata-query-service

How can I format this SPARQL query

```
SELECT ?id WHERE {
   ?id wdt:P1566 "6359304"
}
```

So that it will accept multiple genome IDs as value.

I tried

```
SELECT ?id WHERE { ?id wdt:P1566 } VALUES ?id {("6359304"), ("6299427")}
```

or

```
SELECT ?id WHERE {
   ?id wdt:P1566
   FILTER (?id IN ("6359304", "6299427")
}
```

Including a lot of variations of the two above. No luck however.

Comment: regarding your tries, it always has to be a triple pattern as it has to match RDF triples, but both of your queries just have tuples. You should also check the syntax of `VALUES` clause, there is no comma between items, that only holds when using `IN`. Long story short, it should be `SELECT ?s WHERE { VALUES ?id {"6359304" "6299427"} ?s wdt:P1566 ?id }`

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks a lot. This was the one I needed! I do not know anything about SPARQL and this is really the only thing I needed. Thanks a lot. You can make an answer of it if you want to get the medal.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by UninformedUser in the comments:

```
SELECT ?s 
WHERE { 
  VALUES ?id {"6359304" "6299427"} # separated by space, not by comma
  ?s wdt:P1566 ?id . # triple, not tuple
}
```